# Character's feet moving strangely between keyframes of walk cycle

Tags: animation, bones

I'm very new to blender and was trying to make a basic skipping animation to learn some of the basics. Between two of the keyframes, the feet or hands may sometimes act weird and suddenly flip up or rotate, causing the animation to look broken. Since my two key frames seem solid, I don't know why there's unexpected movement between them. Why might this be? In the gif, the key frames are at frames 30 and 35. You can see at frame 33 the foot bone suddenly flips up. [image][image]

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of the rot curves of the foot roll bone in the graph editor.

Comment: Added that to the post-- looks like that's the problem. Do you know how it could end up this way without me trying to do so? I hadn't even touched the graph editor, so I don't know how it would have gotten this.